# Why sometimes Visual Studio debugger doesn't offer to open the current instance?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 installed. I have a 'debugger' statement in some javascript. When I run the app from within VS, sometimes the VS  prompt does not offer the current instance. I only see options to open new instances of VS 2008 & VS 2010.

What are some circumstances that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

If the instance is already in debug mode, it will not appear on the list.